# How can domain events return data?

Tags: dns, domain-driven-design

I am in the process of making a web service and would like to apply domain patterns to it. I am having problems making my domain entities have more behavior. I would like to do something like this

```
    public void DoSomethingApi()
    {
        CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();
        Customer customer = customerRepository.GetCustomer("myId");
        customer.DoSomething();
    }
```

to make my customer entity have more behavior I have tried the following:

```
public class Customer
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // how do I do this?
        // I need a repository and a bunch of services todo work here
    }   

    // using double dispatch
    public void DoSomething1(DoSomethingService service)
    {
        service.DoSomething();
    }

    // using domain services directly 
    public void DoSomething2()
    {
        new DoSomethingService().DoSomething();
    }

    // using event broker and domain events
    public void DoSomething3()
    {
        EventBroker.FireEvent<DoSomethingEvent>();
    }

    // using Actions
    public Action DoSomethingAction4 { get; set; }
}
```

All methods have pros and cons, but I liked the use of domain events the most. However how do you return a value with domain events? how do you handle rollbacks if the method is in a transaction?

or maybe domain events is really just for notification (fire and forget)...

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example, given a well designed system you should not need to do it this way. One Unit Of work should affect only one aggregate (ideally). If a event needs to be (rollbacked) try look at compensating events.

Comment: I'd advise 2 big best practices.  Don't expose your domain objects over web services and flatten and simplify your message objects (like you would with a well crafted view model).

Comment: I am thinking of a case where the there is a Role and an ACtion, for exmaple Customer.PlaceOrder(Order), this is code that I would like to have on the customer class and not in a service like OrderService.

Also, the entities are not used to be sent over the wire - this is a simple example, but in the real application the entity is converted into a DTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From how I understand and practice it, a domain event is something that already happened. (In our convention, the event names are always in the past tense). Publishing a domain event just "let's the world know" that something happened. Any event listeners then act accordingly independent of what caused the event. The event carries information of what happened It does not return anything.

As such, a domain event cannot be rolled back. A transaction inside a listener that gets triggered can be rolled back but not the event itself.

Edit: It is as you mentioned - fire and forget.